# Is it possible to select for a camera which objects it should render?

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm thinking to use 2 cameras, one for the normal scene view (user view) and another placed on top of the field (top view) for the radar view. The output of that camera could be placed on the radar object as texture. But I want this camera to just render certain objects (enemies) not everything it "Sees". Is it possible? or there is a better approach to the radar/sonar view implementation?

Comment: Have a look at layers: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Layers

Comment: It looks like thing I need:) let me see if I can implement this:) thanks.